# How to send events from HTML running inside a UIWebView to native Objective-C code?

Tags: ios, html, mobile, uiwebview

I want to integrate a full HTML framework (ie HTML/CSS/JavaScript) inside an iOS app and make the UIWebView in charge of running the HTML content being able to communicate with the rest of the native Objective-C source code.

**Direction 1: from Objective-C to HTML inside a UIWebView**

The way to make the rest of the source send messages to the HTML content is pretty straightforward: i can just call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` on the Objective-C side and implement JavaScript methods the right way.

**Direction 2: from HTML inside a UIWebView to Objective-C**

This is the way I can't really figure out. My only idea so far is to make my app a local web server and make the HTML request stuff to it. But I have no idea how to do that although I suppose it can be bone as I believe apps such as Things, VLC or 1Password might use this kind of features.

Any idea to make this *direction 2* work or any new perspective to make events inside HTML content being sent to Objective-C code is welcome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have done this using jQuery and UIWebViewDelegate:

JavaScript (jQuery mobile):

```
$("#bloodType").change(function() {
    url = $("#bloodType option:selected").text();
    url = "donordialog:bloodTypeChanged(" + url + ")";
    window.location = url;
});
```

So, the resulting URL looks like: `donordialog:bloodTypeChanged(typeAB-)`

In my objc code:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *URL = [request URL];
    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"donordialog"])
    {
        // now we need to figure out the function part
        NSString *functionString = [URL resourceSpecifier];

        if ([functionString hasPrefix:@"bloodTypeChanged"])
        {
            // the blood type has changed, now do something about it.
            NSString *parameter = [functionString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"bloodTypeChanged" withString:@""];

            // remove the '(' and then the ')'
            parameter = [parameter stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
            parameter = [parameter stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];

            // log the paramter, as I don't know what to do with it right now
            NSLog(@"%@", parameter);
        }

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This code was copied verbatim from a project I am currently working on, and can verify that this works.

Comment: The code is not safe if the argument contains another "(" or ")" or "bloodTypeChanged" because of the global string replacement. It works only for simple messages.

Answer (score 5):

I just created a library that will do this for you. It supports two-way communication between your web app and iOS about through JSON, relying heavily on this method. Check it out: https://github.com/tcoulter/jockeyjs

Answer (score 3):

The way you usually talk back from JavaScript is by opening a fictional URL (by `window.location`), and then implementing `UIWebViewDelegate`'s `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to ignore the navigation and handle what needs to be done instead.

(On Mac OS X WebKit, you can supply Objective-C objects that have JavaScript functions to the web site, but this is not available in iOS.)

Comment: And then get data or messages from the NSURLRequest? Interesting.

Comment: What is an example of an Ajax request that would cause a jump into shouldStartLoadWithRequest?

Comment: @Mr.Peckington: say, loading `foobar://xyz`. I am unsure as to whether the `foobar:` URL scheme needs to be registered by your Info.plist in order for the request to not fail immediately.

Comment: @DirtyHenry: I don't think this is possible since URLs in this manner on iOS just launch things. You use it as a trigger to send the command, then you presumably do what's asked and call back into JavaScript using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` with the answer. Richard's answer has a code example of this.

Comment: @Jesper Richard IS using NSURLRequest to get a bloodTypeChanged message ;)

Comment: @DirtyHenry: Sure, but he's not passing the data along back as a response which will flow out as an AJAX response, which is what I thought you were saying, and which would be nice to be able to do.

Comment: @Jesper have you tried getting AJAX requests to work with this solution? From what I have tried AJAX requests don't seem to trigger the callback to `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` -- dang lost edit karma to community as I wasn't logged in !

Comment: Maybe it doesn't - I didn't try it, but I thought it'd still be regarded as a request. By the way, in iOS 7 or later, the solution I'd recommend is the JavaScriptCore bidirectional Obj-C-JavaScript bridge.

Answer (score -5):

PhoneGap was built exactly for this

Comment: This is not a constructive answer. It reminds me of the times when SO wasn't around and technical forum answers were 99% "search on google".

Comment: If you say that PhoneGap should solve the problem, I think that showing an example would be nice.